# How to change the state of history object in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was trying to modify the entry of the current history object instead of creating a new one but I got this error

> history.replace is not a function

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU75m.png)

```
//My attempts were:

import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


   history.replaceState( position );

   history.replace( null, position );
```

I'm using version ^16.13.1" of react-router-dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router` uses the `history` package, so you have to [import it](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const position = '/logged-in';
history.replace(position);
```

With vanilla Javascript, if you just want to update the URL without reloading any components, you can use `window.history.replaceState({}, title, position)`.